# How to display busy status in Kentico custom module

Tags: kentico

I have a custom module that contains a button. The button click performs a process that sometimes takes 5-10 seconds to complete. Is there a way in Kentico to display a custom busy message like the "Loading" message that Kentico displays during lengthy processes?  I would like to show the same "Loading" msg that Kentico shows with my own custom message.

Answer (score 1):

If your module is built using the out of the box page templates and webparts, this is included by default.  If it is not and you're using custom aspx template pages, you'll need to ensure that the page in inherited properly and add that in.  You might want to reference another out of the box module which is using code already like the Users in the Membership module.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its using the out-of-the-box page template. But how would I be able to know for sure? The partial class inherits from CMSPage 
public partial class CMSModules_CompanyInfo_Pages_General : CMSPage

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was I didn't setup the trigger in the General.aspx file.

<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefreshLocations"/>

Comment: If you're building your modules within Kentico then it is using the standard out of the box portal page templates.  If you're building them in code then you're using another approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The module was built before I ever started working here. So, I'm not sure how it was done. However, I edited the General.aspx page and added the button mentioned. But, I didn't add the PostBackTrigger like the "Save" button has. The Save button causes the msg to appear. So I added a trigger and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on how things are set up.

If the button executes an Ajax Panel (it does a postback through an ajax call), then you can capture the ajax call and put your loading message there.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var AjaxHandler = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
AjaxHandler.add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);
AjaxHandler.add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

function beginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
// Waiting
}

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
// close waiting
}
</script>
```

If you have it postbacking on the page, you can try to put a hook when the button is clicked to show the waiting, when the page refreshes then the waiting will of course be gone.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
  // Waiting
});
```